# Net-SNMP snmptrap not sending EngineBoots

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, pysnmp, snmp-trap, snmpd

I am trying to send out 'net-snmp' SNMPv3 "snmptrap" command from a command line with  option "-Z 20, 235". However, i do not see the expected "EngineBoots" and "EngineTimes" values when i check with "Wireshark". I see "msgAuthoritativeEngineBoots=1" and "msgAuthoritativeEngineTime=0".

Anyone had that experienced the same? Or is it a bug in net-snmp? i use version 5.5-60

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug, as it is desired.

For SNMP v3 TRAP, the `snmptrap` process should set `msgAuthoritativeEngineBoots` and `msgAuthoritativeEngineTime` based on itself, not the TRAP receiver process, so anything passed via `-Z` should be ignored.

You might get some hints from articles like http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/snmptrap-v3.html

> SNMPv3 TRAPs are a bit more complicated in some ways, but it makes sense the protocol works this way if you spend a long time thinking about it.
>
> I should go rambling on here about the intricate details of v3 engineIDs, INFORMs, TRAPs, engineID discovery, secret keys, passwords, localized keys, etc. But it took the SNMPv3 working group 18223 lines of text (RFCs 2570 - 2575) to try and explain it all, so I don't think I'll reiterate that here.

Comment: Hm.. thanks for the link. the link specifies snmptrapd.conf mods, but my trap is sent to NMS called Spectrum. CA Spectrum compares the snmpEngineBoots value and, if it has incremented, communication resumes. If the snmpEngineBoots value has not incremented, then CA Spectrum does not resume communication.

Comment: so, what is the purpose of "-Z" option?

Comment: `-Z` is used for all other v3 scenarios than TRAP. That means GET/GET BULK/SET/INFORM.